# AWS Cloudformation when linked with gitLabs using webhooks creates a subfolder inside zip in AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, gitlab, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to deploy my GITLabs repository code to my AWS instance on every commit i do on repo.

I have created webhook using **ZipDownloadWebHookApi** URL form Output tab of my stack. I have followed [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/integrating-git-with-aws-codepipeline/) link for doing all the stuff.

I am using the stack cloud template specified [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/git-to-codepipeline-prod-us-west-2/v1.0/git2s3.template)

The **zip** which is being created by **cloudFormation** inside specified **S3 Bucket** is having a subfolder, which is containing whole git repository code.

So the issue I am facing is, when I use this zip as an **object** in **AWS  CodeDeploy** it does not find the **appspecs.yml** file and deployment stops before **beforeInstall** event with following error-

> No such file or directory -
>   /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/1d0d3a00-435a-4td1-87d8-4ad40222e6f9/d-LJS5Q7WGN/deployment-archive/appspec.yml

Can you please suggest me what should I follow after this to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

You could, wuth [GitLab 13.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/10/22/gitlab-13-5-released/#template-for-deploying-to-aws-ec2) (October 2020), follow a template example which would illustrate the all delivery process:

> ### Template for Deploying to AWS EC2
>
> To help you deploy to AWS Elastic Cloud Compute (EC2) more efficiently, we created a template that shows you how to get started.
> This template allows you to:
>
> - provision your own infrastructure by first leveraging the [AWS CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) API.
> - push your previously built artifact to an [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) bucket and deploy the content to an [AWS EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance.
>
> Users can include the template in their configuration, specify a few variables, and their application will be deployed and ready to go in no time.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_deployment/#provision-and-deploy-to-your-aws-elastic-compute-cloud-ec2) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/201742).

---

And with [GitLab 13.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/11/22/gitlab-13-6-released/#auto-deploy-to-ec2) (November 2020):

> ### Auto Deploy to EC2
>
> Auto DevOps has been expanded to support deployments to Amazon Web Services. You can now deploy to AWS Cloud Compute (EC2) and take advantage of Auto DevOps, even without Kubernetes.
>
> To enable this workflow, you must enable Auto DevOps and define the AWS-typed environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, and `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`. This allows you to provision your own infrastructure by leveraging the [AWS CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) API.
>
> Then, you can push your previously built artifact to an [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) bucket, and deploy the content to an [AWS EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance.
> Your EC2 deployment then automatically builds you a complete, automatic delivery pipeline without extra manual steps.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_deployment/#custom-build-job-for-auto-devops) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/216008).